# how to export and reuse 3rd party type in typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, types, reference, package

I have a package, that use a 3rd party package API (mostly export the 3rd party package). how do i export the 3rd party package API types in my own package?

Example:

- react have @types/react
- we create a package called ReactWrapper. and we want to continuously and use @types/react types and export them as part of our own package.

Meaning, how to reuse existing types of a 3rd party package.

Answer (score 0):

You just export them, like you would anything else.

```
// my-package/index.ts
export type { Component, Dispatch } from "react";
```

Then import them from your package like any export when you want to use them.

```
import type { Component, Dispatch } from "my-package";
```

Comment: interesting! however we are looking to import the react wrapper. but it keep saying that the types "cannot be named without a reference". import ReactWrapper from 'react-wrapper'; // no types!